# question about forms, how do i get instant user in a form field pyhton django

Tags: python, django, forms, view, model

i have build some user to user message function. i have sender, receiver and text see below. The user now must choose his email and then the email where the message should go.
But what i want is that the user dont need tho choose it self i need a form function that query instantly request.user. but i dont know how to implement that on form. And that the user is not shown in the receiver list. Srry  for my bad english hope  you understand me.

views.py

```
def mailEMployee(request):
    mail = Mailsysthem.objects.filter(ontvanger=request.user)
    receiver = Mailsysthem.objects.filter(ontvanger=request.user)
    sender = Mailsysthem.objects.filter(zender=request.user)
    user = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=request.user)
    form = Mailsythemform()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = Mailsythemform(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       return redirect('mail')
   context={
   'form':form,
   'receiver':receiver,
   'sender':sender.all,
   'mail':mail,
   'user':user
    }
   return render(request,'emp/mail.html', context)
```

Forms.py

```
class Mailsythemform(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model= Mailsysthem
    fields= ['zender','ontvanger','subject','text']
```

models.py

```
class Mailsysthem(models.Model):
zender = models.ForeignKey(to=CustomUser, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='Zender')
ontvanger = models.ForeignKey(to=CustomUser, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='Ontvanger')
subject = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
text = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Bericht')
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
solftdelete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
mail_opened = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

url.py

```
   path('mailemployee/', views.mailEMployee, name='mail'),
```

Comment: You can easily get sender's email from its model in your function. I am not sure if I could understand your question correctly.

Comment: i have found it thx alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide initial value to your `ModelForm` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values)) as following:

```
form = JournalForm(initial={'sender': user.id})
```